# Convert Parquet to JSON

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

How do I convert Parquet file with null fields to JSON using PySpark. I need the null fields to be zeroes in the output JSON file. I tried writing

```
df.withColumn('x', when(
        col('x').isNull(),
        0.0
    ).otherwise(col('x'))
```

Is there any better way to do it?